# Using objectId as an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In javascript we can find the location of a specific string within an array using indexOf of

```
> ["aa","bb"].indexOf("bb")
1
```

I want to do the same with objectIds in mongodb for example

```
> ids= db.foo1.distinct('_id');
[
        ObjectId("50d38d775f2b6c6e3393d6b0"),
        ObjectId("50d38d835f2b6c6e3393d6b1")
]
> id0=db.foo1.findOne()._id
ObjectId("50d38d775f2b6c6e3393d6b0")
```

I am looking for a way to do something like **ids.indexOf(id0)** that will give me the location of id0 within ids. I can convert everything to strings and then use the indexOf but I was hoping to find a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a one-liner for this and you'd need to use a for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) { 
    if (ids[i].equals(id0)) { ixOfId0 = i; break; } 
}
```

Comment: I did a similar thing. I wish there was a smarter way to do this. Thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 1):

If the list doesn't change frequently (or is only added to), consider just adding the documents with an index: `{ i: 0, r: ObjectId('....') }`, where the `i` field represents the index.

Then `db.foo1.find( { 'list.r' : ObjectId('...') })`. The result would have the index by looking at the field `i` in the resulting document.

But, if the list is long, this is always going to be an O(N) operation as it has to search through every array element to find the match. You may need to create an index to improve performance.

Comment: The data set is way too big and I can't change it  but thanks for the comment

Comment: How are you using the "index" value? Seems like the data may not be structured efficiently for MongoDB? Also, there's no guarantee of order unless you've explicitly put them in an array. Using Distinct isn't going to guarantee a particular order (and using `distinct` with `_id` doesn't make sense as `_id` must be unique/distinct per mongodb).